# Translating add to cart woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to translate add to cart button. I have 2 code snippets from woocommerce documentation here are they:

FOR SINGLE PRODUCT - THIS ONE WORKS

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 
'woo_custom_cart_button_text' );    // 2.1 +

function woo_custom_cart_button_text() {

    return __( 'My Button Text', 'woocommerce' );

}
```

FOR PRODUCT ARCHIVE - NOT WORKING?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 
'woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text' );    // 2.1 +

function woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text() {

    return __( 'My Button Text', 'woocommerce' );

}
```

I dont know why this other is not working. Is there some fix. I am using DIVI wordpress theme. And also overwrote my loop archive addtocart.php so I can display quantity input. This is also snippet from woocommerce documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use the plugin [Change WooCommerce Add to Cart Text](https://wordpress.org/plugins/change-woocommerce-add-to-cart-button-text/). **Install** it, and **Activate**.

Then go to **wp-admin → Settings → Reading** and fill your translation on **Add To Cart Button Text For Single Page** for Single Page and fill your translation on **Add To Cart Button Text For Archive Pages** for Archive Pages.

I've done this, and it's work.